# Drools Fusion handling conflicts across drl files

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion, drools-kie-server

I am using drools fusion for CEP. I have 2 rule files.
File 1 - 
Rule - do an action on each event

```
rule "action on each event"
when $event
then action_1
end
```

File 2 -
Rule - do an action when event count>10

```
rule "action on count>10"
when accumulate(event $cnt count(1); $cnt > 10)
then
   action_2.
```

Here Is rule 1 and 2 conflicting. Will drool won't retract event until count is 10 and then retract event when new event comes , hence action 1 Rule1 will fire 10 times on every event instead of 1 ?

Comment: Could you try and edit your question so that (a) the rule text is closer to reality, b) the limits (10? 2?) match c) you show where an event is actually retracted. - The rules are not conflicting. - As a preliminary answer: Drools does not retract an event when a rule with that event is fired, but the rule is usually not fired again for that event.

Comment: Have edited the question - 
For The rules are not conflicting. - As a preliminary answer: Drools does not retract an event when a rule with that event is fired, but the rule is usually not fired again for that event.  How does drools ensure not to retract the event since drools cannot retract the event until atleast 10 events are stored. So on every new event count will increase and for Rule 1 it will fire action every time for each event in memory or not?

Comment: It's unclear how rules 1 and 2 are actually written and what happens in either rule. Until you fix this, no definite answer can be given. Preliminary: Whenever there is a new fact matching a pattern, the rule may fire even if the rule has fired before for other facts.